# Como fazer o agendamento de um evento em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, agendamento

**Informações:** Gostaria de saber como fazer para realizar um `Agendamento` de um evento, ou seja uma funçao qualquer que eu passaria como parâmetro, que executaria tal `dia`/`mês`/`ano` tal `hora`:`minuto` que eu também passaria como parâmetro.

## Exemplo:

```js
agendar('12/02/2014', '14:55', function() { alert("Está na hora!"); });
```

Apareceria um alerta dizendo `"Está na hora!"` quando chegar no dia `12/02/2014` no momento `14:55`.

Tem como fazer isso em Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bem, você pode fazer o seguinte, pelo que entendi você quer como se fosse um `Scheduler` que seria tipo um agendamento para executar uma determinada função.

Fiz de forma que você possa informar o intervalo também, para ser mais customizado.

No caso, para não ter que usar `setInterval()` por causa que ele não irá ter parada, realizei o melhor método em questões de performance, pois ele irá apenas executar até conseguir igualar a `DataAtual` com a `DataNecessaria` e assim executar sua função, e parar.

Utilizei de recursividade para realizar tal feito, como você pode ver tenho uma `função 1` chamando uma `função 2` que chama a minha `função 1` inicial novamente com os mesmos parâmetros, com um intervalo passado por parâmetro.

## [Veja como funciona esta tal função](http://jsfiddle.net/6pqBG/):

```js
function agendar(data, tempo, func, cond, intervalo) {
  var aryData   = data.split('/'),
      dia       = parseInt(aryData[0]),
      mes       = parseInt(aryData[1]),
      ano       = parseInt(aryData[2]);
  var aryTempo  = tempo.split(':'),
      hora      = parseInt(aryTempo[0]),
      minuto    = parseInt(aryTempo[1]);
      console.log("Necessario Data: "+dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano+" Tempo: "+hora+":"+minuto);
  var agora     = new Date();
  var diaAtual  = agora.getDate(),
      mesAtual  = (agora.getMonth()+1),
      anoAtual  = agora.getFullYear(),
      horaAtual = agora.getHours(),
      minAtual  = agora.getMinutes();
      console.log("Atual Data: "+diaAtual+"/"+mesAtual+"/"+anoAtual+" Tempo: "+horaAtual+":"+minAtual);
  if (ano == anoAtual && mes == mesAtual && dia == diaAtual && hora == horaAtual && minuto == minAtual) {
    func();
  } else if (cond) {
    cond = false;
    return setTimeout(scheduler, intervalo, data, tempo, func, cond, intervalo);
  }
}
function scheduler(data, tempo, func, cond, intervalo) {
  return setTimeout(agendar, 0, data, tempo, func, true, intervalo);
}
```

> ## Informações da Função:
>
> **agendar(**[***data***],[**tempo**],[**funcao**],[**true**],[**intervalo**])
>
> ## Parâmetros:
>
> **data**      - (*dd/mm/aaaa*) **String** - Data em Dia/Mes/Ano(formato padrão), por exemplo `"01/01/2014"` para execução da função.
>
> **tempo**     - (*hh:mm*) - **String** - Tempo em Hora:Minuto(formato 24h), por exemplo `"23:00"` para a execução da função.
>
> **funcao**    - (*function(){}*) - **Function** Mande uma referência de função ou uma funcão em sí para este parâmetro, ela será executada assim que chegar na data/tempo que você pediu.
>
> **recursão**  - (true) - **Boolean** - Utilize sempre `true` para este parâmetro, para manter a recursividade entre as funções, apenas utilize `false` se você quiser desabilitar a recursividade(não recomendado).
>
> **intervalo** - (*em milissegundos*) - **Integer** - Tempo de intervalo para checar se a data atual é igual a data fornecida, em milissegundos(**Cuidado! não coloque um intervalo muito grande caso você utilize precisão a nível de minutos!**)
>
> ## Exemplo
>
> Se você executar:

```
agendar('11/02/2014', '14:55', function() { alert("Está na hora!"); }, true, 5000);
```

> Você terá como resultado logs no console do seu navegador a cada 5 segundos informando o tempo necessário e o tempo atual, quando os dois se igualarem você terá um `alert("Está na hora!")` executado em sua tela.
>
> ## Informações Adicionais:
>
> Acredito que o parâmetro recursão não seria realmente necessário, porém não obtive sucesso em tentar criar uma função sem ele.
>
> Também, não implementei o segundo, pois não sei se você realmente vai querer utilizar precisão de segundo, pois o intervalo teria que ser (recomendado ser) de `1s` para não ocorrer de passar direto da data.

**Acredito que eu tenha entendido o que você pediu, pois estou sujeito a alterar minha função se necessário, também, qualquer crítica/opinião será levada em conta.**

Creditos ao **@AndreLeria** por me ajudar em um problema que eu tive com o `setTimeout()` :)